# Best way to constantly "check" fragment visibility/keyboard visibility in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I would like to continuously check if a fragment is visible or better yet. If the keyboard is present in an Android application. What would be the best method to go about this?

I'm not too familiar with the activity lifecycle, but I'm hoping this is correct way. The code below is written in the OnCreate method. I need it to run constantly though.

```
if (timeFragment.isVisible()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Wehat do you mean by "if the keyboard is present"?  For example: do you mean focus?  Or if the soft keyboard is displayed?  Or something else?

Comment: If the soft keyboard is present.

Answer (score 1):

For a fragment, the function setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisible) is fired everytime the fragment becomes visible or invisible.

This will conserve resources compared to polling. In timeFragment:

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisible) {
    if (isVisible)
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Time becoming visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Time becoming invisible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Alright, so I put this code exactly into my timeFragment.java, right below my `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated`. No errors in eclipse, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Interesting. This code has been working for me. The only thing I can think of is to add super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisible). Also, does this function get called if you are in debugger? Another thing maybe to add the @Override flag to confirm that there are no typos in the function definition.

Comment: Android Dev says, that `setUserVisibleHint` is for API level 15. I added @Override, but still nothing. Ugh. Looks like this is gonna be a pain to do.

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is to check whether the soft keyboard is currently on-screen (as I am assuming from your replies to my comments above), you can use this rather hacky [listener](http://illusionsandroid.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-soft-virtual-keyboard-listener.html) approach.